# Number Representation

Tags: mathematics

The following examples and statements are correct:

`Count to twenty: 1, 10, 11, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1101, 1110, 1111, 10001, 10010, 10011, 10101, 10110, 10111, 11000

110 x 110 = 100010

1011 x 11 = 101000

10000011 / 1011 = 1011 (Corrected to canonical form; answer uses previous non-canonical form for reasoning)

(100000 x 10) + 1 = 1000000

(100000 x 10) + 1 = 111101`

**How do you represent seventy?**

#### *BONUS QUESTIONS*

(*please answer these only if you are sure you have ‘doped out’ the rules for number representation.*)

> If all numbers given except “forty-seven” are shown only in ‘canonical’ form, what is the rule for determining the ‘canonical’ form of a number?
>
>  If all numbers given except “forty-seven” are shown only in ‘canonical’ form, what are the alternative representations for those numbers in the examples that have them?

Comment: if you get the first part, no doubt you have figured the second part...

Comment: Well, yes, that would be the case.

Comment: Shouldn't the last number in `count to twenty` be `11001`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - No. All of the examples are correct.

Comment: The last two equations given have the same left-hand side but different right-hand sides. (1) Is that definitely correct?, (2) are we to assume that seventy has exactly one representation?, (3) if we aren't, do we need to give *all* of them or *one* of them for a correct answer?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - (1) Yes, the two representations are both correct. I consider one of them "canonical", but I'm not providing enough information to tell you which one, so I'm not expecting "canonical" answers. (2) No, you shouldn't assume that any given number has only one representation. Many do, some do not. Except for the example, I'm not telling you which. (3) One answer meets the request, but I'd be more inclined to accept an answer that gives them all.

Comment: ***I HAVE CORRECTED ONE OF THE EXAMPLES (the last one) - I CAN'T DO MATH, EITHER.***

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - I inadvertently lied in my response to your (1); I've corrected the example so that it's no longer a lie.

Comment: 70 can be factorized as 10 × 7 or 14 × 5 which is 1011 × 1000 or 10001 × 110. Simplifying either of these should be a valid answer then.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay - I'm not looking for an equation that will yield 70; I'm looking for the representation, much as the representation of 'ten' is '1011'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the first example we can see that the first five digits have binary values equivalent to decimal 1,2,3,7,13
>  With this in mind, the next 2 examples show us what the 6th digit is, because 110(5) ^ 2 = 25 meaning that the 6th digit would be 23. Clarified by  1011(10) * 11(3) = 101000(30), 23 + 7. 
>  the 4th example shows us that the 8th digit is 97 since 1011(10) ^ 2 = 10000100(100), 97 + 3.
>  the 5th and 6th examples confirm the 7th digit is 47, by showing that (100000(23) x 10(2)) + 1 = 111101 (23 + 13 + 7 + 3 + 1) = 1000000(47)

Therefore 70 is:

> 1100000 (47 + 23)

Comment: 25 is 100010 and 2 is 10, okay...But i dont think you can subtract 2 from 25 and say 23 is 100000. Because those operations are not valid in this case

Comment: @MITURAJ - I can't? It sure looks like I can...

Comment: i mean for eg: 
3 is represented here as 11 ....1 is represented as 1 ...
4 = 3 + 1 ...But i cannot write 4 = 11+1 = 100 ....cz its incorrect ,as here 4 is represented as 101. That is what I meant.

Comment: @MITURAJ - If you understand the rule for the representation, you will find that all of the operations are valid and work correctly.

Comment: It looks like this is basically right, though. I think the actual sequence is 1,2,3,7,13,23,47,97 and perhaps the principle is that the (n+1)th place corresponds to the nearest prime to twice what's in the nth place. Then 70 would be, e.g., 1100000.

Comment: I found my bad math and edited my mistake. Thanks @GarethMcCaughan, your answer matches as well

Comment: I thought the pattern just skips over numbers whose binary representation ends with an even number of 0s? e.g. 100,  1100, 10000 and 10100 are skipped to become 101, 1101, 10001 and 10101 respectively. I made a short script to generate all numbers to 150 last night, but the remaining operations dont add up...

Comment: @VotBear Right: that works fine for the counting-to-20 but not for the other facts we're given, therefore it is not the intended pattern.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - I'll have to do some checking to see whether your rule and mine are actually equivalent, but I will acknowledge that you're at least in the right ballpark.

Comment: @Joe - after you corrected your math, it was appropriate for me to delete my original comment to you.

Comment: The rule that I used for determining the place values is that the value of any given place is the lowest prime number less-than-or-equal-to the sum of all the values to its right, plus one. Where a number can be represented in multiple ways, the "canonical" representation is the representation that maximizes the "to-the-rightness" of the most '1's - e.g., the canonical representation of '3' is 11, not 100.